# Starting with Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

This is a very stupid question I am asking. I know Java pretty well that is Java SE. Now I have started learning Java EE. But I don't understand do I need to download anything from a java site to learn Java EE? I am using head first servlet and jsp.

When I started learning Java they had asked me to download the Java EE SDK from the website. Do I need to download something similar to that while learning Java EE? I have installed and configured the Tomcat server but I'm confused if I need to download anything else, although the book doesn't ask me to.

Comment: Unless you're supporting legacy products, it's J2EE (Java 2 Enterprise Edition) anymore. The current version is called JEE6 (Java 6 Enterprise Edition). Hooray for marketing! See also: [Java EE version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history).

Comment: Your book is outdated. Very outdated. Order a new edition.

Comment: @Matt Ball +1. It's also no longer J2SE. It's JavaSE (and has been for several years).

Answer (score 2):

Often, when people say that they 'want to learn Java EE', the real situation is that they don't know what they need. Java EE is a random assortment of technologies. Some useful, some awful (EJB). Some of the most useful moved into SE in version 6, in any case. You should look to learn the specific things that you need to accomplish the task at hand. In many cases, the most useful resource for you won't be anything that comes directly from Snoracle.

Comment: Java EE is not a random assortment of technologies, but an integrated platform of which most parts are also useable standalone (e.g. outside Java EE). EJB is no longer awful. It stopped being that in 2006, when EJB 3.0 was released, which is actually pretty cool ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused. All you need to learn java is the JDK (Java Development Kitt) and the JRE (Java Runtime Environment). JDK includes, JRE, so just install JDK:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

And for Java EE, you need the Java EE SDK:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/download-141771.html

Additionally, you can get an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse. Google will help you on that ;)

Comment: JDK includes JRE, so there's no need to download both separately

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NetBeans as your IDE? If so, you can go to the Module preferences box and download everything you need in one package.  I believe it is Tools | Modules or the like.

Comment: Hey netbeans is good.... Theres a tutorial of hw to use struts....

Comment: I am a big fan of eclipse but net beans is also kool